# How to generate java classes from wsdl having multiple xsd?

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2java

I am new to soap service. I have to change WSDL to java classes. I have tried placing it in resource folder and change it. But I am unable to do it . When I am setting the goals in pom.xml. It is giving errors in execute method.

```
Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java failed: file:/C:/Workspace/demo/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bene.wsdl [556,5]: 'maintainBene' is already defined
file:/C:/Workspace/demo/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bene.wsdl [20,5]: (related to above error) the first definition appears here
file:/C:/Workspace/demo/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bene.wsdl [733,5]: 'maintainBeneResponse' is already defined
file:/C:/Workspace/demo/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bene.wsdl [197,5]: (related to above error) the first definition appears here
file:/C:/Workspace/demo/src/main/resources/wsdl/Bene.wsdl [940,5]: 'Common' is already defined
```